# Como buscar vários valores de uma planinha

Tags: microsoft-excel

Olá, eu tenho uma planilha com muitos dados, e gostaria de separa-los cada um em uma planilha por categoria, exemplo: todos os produtos que estão com a data de setembro são mostrados em outra planilha ou todos os códigos de produtos que se repetirem são colocados em uma planilha separada, existe alguma função pra isso como se fosse um procv mas pra um conjunto de valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso em uma "**macro**" do **Excel**. O código abaixo em **VBA** faz o essencial do que você precisa e é similar à macro.

O primeiro passo é classificar a planilha de dados conforme a categoria que precisa separar. Se não pode alterar a planilha original, copie os dados para outra planilha e classifique (o código mostra como copiar para outra planilha).

Uma vez com os dados classificados fica fácil verificar que **faixa de dados** corresponde à **categoria** que quer separar.

Chamei de **Planilha1** a planilha de dados e de **Planilha2** a que irá receber os dados de uma categoria.

Veja que uso duas variáveis do tipo "**string**", uma com a faixa a copiar e outra com a faixa a colar.

```
Sheets("Planilha1").Activate
'Ativa a Planilha de dados

Planilha.Rows(FaixaParaCopiar).Select
'Seleciona faixa a copiar 

Selection.Copy
'Copia os dados selecionados para a área de transferência

Sheets("Planilha2").Activate
'Ativa a Planilha para receber uma categoria de dados

Planilha.Rows(FaixaOndeColar).Select
'Seleciona e prepara para colar

ActiveSheet.Paste
'Cola na Planilha da categoria escolhida
```

Pode testar que funciona!

Não tem uma "função" que faça isso de uma vez, há várias soluções além do VBA, como, por exemplo, usar "macros" ou a "tabela dinâmica" (vale a pena conhecer, se for o caso).